# SwiftUI - Create scrollable horizontal calendar-like view

Tags: arrays, swift, date, swiftui, calendar

I have to develop a scrollable horizontal calendar-like view, something like this.
[image]

The final goal is to create an infinite scrollable view. I'm facing some challenges that I'm not sure how to address. I show you the code I have for now, that is far away from what it should be in the end:

```swift
var body: some View {
    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
        LazyHStack {
            ForEach(datesToShow, id: \.self) { value in
                VStack {
                    Text("\(value.day)")
                    Text(value.toString(.custom("MMMM")).capitalized)
                        .padding(.top)
                }
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .background(.purple)
            }
        }
    }
    .frame(height: 200)
    .onAppear {
        
    }
}
```

`datesToShow` is an array of dates that contains dates between today - 10 days and today + 10 days. Now, the hard time starts here:

1. How can I handle dates when I reach one of the two edges of the array/view? Today is Oct. 19th, how can I load dates previous to Oct. 9th or after Oct. 29th and add them to the `datesToShow` array so that they are automatically loaded (with the best performance of course)?
2. Is this the way to achieve the result I need? Do you have different suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `onAppear` to check if the displayed value is the last item of the array and append the next dates or the previous dates if the displayed value is the first item of the array.

Comment: @Timmy you mean on the `VStack` inside the `ForEach`?

Comment: Yes. Since you're using `LazyHStack` the` onAppear` will get called when the item gets displayed.

Comment: @Timmy I will try. May I also prepend the elements to the array without issues? I guess yes, because the uniqueness is guaranteed by the `id` property of the `ForEach`, correct?

Comment: If scrolling is by swiping (as opposed to scrollbars) then you could maybe use a carousel with a fixed number of display panels for the individual dates, say 10. The panels just go round and round. When they come in from the right then the date is incremented, when they come in from the left then it is decremented. This would have low overhead for the container view and you probably wouldn't even need a ```ScrollView```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on my suggestion to use a carousel, here is an example implementation to show it working.

The dates are shown as separate views in a `ZStack`, each with a computed x-offset. A drag gesture on the `ZStack` allows the current date to be changed. When the drag is released, it snaps to the nearest date.

In this example there are 15 underlying views, which just go round and round. I found that it works best to have quite a lot more views than the number that are actually visible, so that when dragging fast you don't get a glimpse of dates in the process of being updated. It would probably be a good idea to make the number dependent on the width of the display, or at least make the size of each view dependent on the width, so that it works on a large display too.

Hope it helps!

*EDIT* Code updated to do it all it one view, a separate `DateView` is not needed. This allows the same `DateFormatter` to be used for all the dates.

*EDIT2* Some variables renamed, to make it clearer how the drag/snap mechanism works.

*EDIT3* I noticed that it was a bit glitchy when the drag position was half-way to another date. Code corrected to use the snapped position for computing the date to display, instead of the drag position.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    let nPanels = 15
    let panelSize: CGFloat = 100
    let gapSize: CGFloat = 10
    let baseDate = Date.now
    let dayOfMonthFormatter = DateFormatter()
    let monthNameFormatter = DateFormatter()

    @State private var snappedDayOffset = 0
    @State private var draggedDayOffset = Double.zero

    init() {
        dayOfMonthFormatter.dateFormat = "d"
        monthNameFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM"
    }

    private var positionWidth: CGFloat {
        CGFloat(panelSize + gapSize)
    }

    private func xOffsetForIndex(index: Int) -> Double {
        let midIndex = Double(nPanels / 2)
        var dIndex = (Double(index) - draggedDayOffset - midIndex).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: Double(nPanels))
        if dIndex < -midIndex {
            dIndex += Double(nPanels)
        } else if dIndex > midIndex {
            dIndex -= Double(nPanels)
        }
        return dIndex * positionWidth
    }

    private func dayAdjustmentForIndex(index: Int) -> Int {
        let midIndex = nPanels / 2
        var dIndex = (index - snappedDayOffset - midIndex) % nPanels
        if dIndex < -midIndex {
            dIndex += nPanels
        } else if dIndex > midIndex {
            dIndex -= nPanels
        }
        return dIndex + snappedDayOffset
    }

    private func dateView(index: Int, halfFullWidth: CGFloat) -> some View {
        let xOffset = xOffsetForIndex(index: index)
        let dayAdjustment = dayAdjustmentForIndex(index: index)
        let dateToDisplay = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: dayAdjustment, to: baseDate) ?? baseDate
        return ZStack {
            Color.purple
                .cornerRadius(10)
            VStack {
                Text(dayOfMonthFormatter.string(from: dateToDisplay))
                Text(monthNameFormatter.string(from: dateToDisplay))
            }
            .foregroundStyle(.white)
        }
        .frame(width: panelSize, height: panelSize)
        .offset(x: xOffset)

        // Setting opacity helps to avoid blinks when switching sides
        .opacity(xOffset + positionWidth < -halfFullWidth || xOffset - positionWidth > halfFullWidth ? 0 : 1)
    }

    private var dragged: some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .onChanged() { val in
                draggedDayOffset = Double(snappedDayOffset) - (val.translation.width / positionWidth)
            }
            .onEnded { val in
                snappedDayOffset = Int(Double(snappedDayOffset) - (val.predictedEndTranslation.width / positionWidth).rounded())
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.15)) {
                    draggedDayOffset = Double(snappedDayOffset)
                }
            }
    }

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            let halfFullWidth = proxy.size.width / 2
            ZStack {
                ForEach(0..<nPanels, id: \.self) { index in
                    dateView(index: index, halfFullWidth: halfFullWidth)
                }
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    .stroke(lineWidth: 3)
                    .opacity(0.7)
                    .frame(width: positionWidth, height: positionWidth)
            }
            .gesture(dragged)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Animation]

Comment: beautiful!!!  
In parallel I tried the .onAppear approach which works for future dates – but makes problems for past dates ...

Comment: This is very cool and efficient! I didn't measure the performance, but I guess it's a lot better than my initial solution.

Comment: @AndreaMarioLufino Thanks for the positive feedback (and thanks too to ChrisR)! I made a couple of minor updates today, mainly to simplify the code and to add clarity. I also noticed that the labels were a bit glitchy when the drag position was half-way between dates, now corrected.

Comment: One thing that would improve this a lot at this point would be to add a binding var to the calendar view, so that we can always get the current selected date. Then you can put it on Github my friend!

Comment: @AndreaMarioLufino This was just intended to be an example solution for the question as posted. You're welcome to adapt it. Other possible enhancements might be to add buttons to jump a month at a time, or tap gestures on the individual dates to allow any visible date to be picked. In the latest edit, the ```.onEnded``` callback for the drag gesture uses ```val.predictedEndTranslation.width```, which gives the drag a bit more momentum. Previously, it was using ```val.translation.width```. But I'm not sure which version is actually better - the change crept in by accident!